# How to verify realUserStatus value in Sign In With Apple

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

When signing in using Sign in with Apple for the first time, it returns a value  `realUserStatus` as a part of `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` in the iOS client. This value indicates whether Apple is confident that the user is real, or not (e.g. it's a script)

My question is how can I verify the value of `realUserStatus` in my backend authentication system? 
Because the realUserStatus is returned to iOS client, and the client should tell my server whether it is a bot or not! How can I know if it's not just a script and telling the server that it is real?

Edit (additional clarification): 
In Apple’s docs it says “ You can skip any additional fraud verification checks or CAPTCHAs that your app normally uses.” but when we use CAPTCHAs, the provider can verify the response, something either Apple doesn’t do, or I can’t find anywhere how to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished a call with an Apple engineer on WWDC online lab.

So from the iOS 14, the realUserIndicator is included in the identity token, and can be verified with the server.

For iOS 13 they don't have a solution.

Answer (score -1):

This flag serves as a basic first validation, meant to be used by your frontend. The identification servers will return this value only when the user first uses Sign in with Apple in your app.

If you want to verify the user on the backend, you should use the user identity token (JWT). You get it from Apple's servers when the user signs in (read here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple).

If you want to verify the user on the upcoming sessions, as an existing user (without the user having to sign in every time), you should develop a system of your own, for creating, saving, and validating a token. Another option is to use Firebase auth framework, which supports apple sign-in.

Comment: Thank you, but then isn’t the realUserStatus completely redundant? In WWDC they said it’s a way to help us catch a script vs a real user. But if my backend can not verify the realUserStatus value, then how can it possibly help me detecting whether the user is real or not.

Comment: And Firebase Auth does not do anything with the realUserStatus.

Answer (score -1):

if you send the fetched user’s information to app server(your backend) you can verify user by the identity token with a rest service.

Apple document says: 
After your app receives the user information, you can verify their associated identity token with the server to confirm that the token is not expired and ensure it has not been tampered with or replayed to your app. For information about retrieving the identity token, see Authenticating Users with Sign in with Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user

Comment: The JWT only contains email address. Nothing about the real user indicator.

Comment: They added realUserIndicator for iOS 14+.